# How to add an arch background section?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

How can I apply the green arch background below?

[image]

I've consulted many sites and AI but can figure out this implementation.

```html
---
layout: default
title: 'About | Redacted'
---
<div class="mx-20">
  <p class="my-12">
    intro goes here
  </p>

  <div class="flex space-x-4">
    {% include social_button.html link="https://www.twitter.com" icon="assets/images/svg/x.svg" label="X" %}
    {% include social_button.html
      link="https://www.linkedin.com/in/redacted/"
      icon="assets/images/svg/linkedin.svg" label="LinkedIn"
    %}
    {% include social_button.html link="mailto" icon="assets/images/envelope.png" label="Email" %}
    {% include social_button.html link="https://www.twitter.com" icon="assets/images/download.png" label="X" %}
  </div>

  green arch background goes here
</div>
```

Comment: You could cheat and use an image. All you'd need is the top part of an ellipse, the arch. The rest you can fill a div with the same color. Its one of many ways to do it.

Comment: Have you looked into either background-image and radial gradient or a circular before pseudo element. If possible avoid putting a spurious extra element into the HTML as it is for visual effect only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an image for a the top arc part:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="mx-20">
  <p class="my-12">
    intro goes here
  </p>

  <div class="flex space-x-4">
    {% include social_button.html link="https://www.twitter.com" icon="assets/images/svg/x.svg" label="X" %}
    {% include social_button.html
      link="https://www.linkedin.com/in/redacted/"
      icon="assets/images/svg/linkedin.svg" label="LinkedIn"
    %}
    {% include social_button.html link="mailto" icon="assets/images/envelope.png" label="Email" %}
    {% include social_button.html link="https://www.twitter.com" icon="assets/images/download.png" label="X" %}
  </div>

  <div class="-mx-20">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 20" class="w-full aspect-[400/20] fill-green-300">
      <path d="M0 20C0 20 50 0 200 0 350 0 400 20 400 20"/>
    </svg>
    <div class="bg-green-300 h-96 px-20">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `<path>` element in the `<svg>` is responsible for the arc shape. Consider reading up [about using SVGs on the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG).

You could also use a [CSS mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) to draw the arc:

```css
.mask {
  mask:
    linear-gradient(0deg, #000, #000) subtract,
    url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 20" id="mask"%3E%3Cpath d="M0 0V20C0 20 50 0 200 0 350 0 400 20 400 20V0"/%3E%3C/svg%3E') no-repeat top / 100%
    ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="mx-20">
  <p class="my-12">
    intro goes here
  </p>

  <div class="flex space-x-4">
    {% include social_button.html link="https://www.twitter.com" icon="assets/images/svg/x.svg" label="X" %}
    {% include social_button.html
      link="https://www.linkedin.com/in/redacted/"
      icon="assets/images/svg/linkedin.svg" label="LinkedIn"
    %}
    {% include social_button.html link="mailto" icon="assets/images/envelope.png" label="Email" %}
    {% include social_button.html link="https://www.twitter.com" icon="assets/images/download.png" label="X" %}
  </div>

  <div class="-mx-20">
    <div class="bg-green-300 h-96 px-20 pt-[5%] mask">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, we use a data-encoded (since we cannot host it as a separate file on Stack Overflow) SVG. We have a fully viewable area "painted" by the `linear-gradient()`, and then we subtract an arc "cut-out" from the top. The advantage of this technique is that you don't need to define the color in two places as per the previous image method. This means you only need to change the color in one place. However, this technique is more complicated and not as intuitive.

Comment: This was the answer that ultimately got me the correct end result. Thank you @wongin
```html
<div class="h-auto mt-14 overflow-x-hidden">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 400 20" class="w-full aspect-[400/20] fill-[#DEE1CE] overflow-hidden">
    <path d="M0 20C0 20 50 0 200 0 350 0 400 20 400 20" />
  </svg>
  <div class="bg-[#DEE1CE] h-auto overflow-hidden">
    <div class="container mx-auto px-8 md:px-20 mt-8 md:mt-0">
      content here...
```